# The usage of "on" and "in"

Tags: prepositions

I am trying to write a sentence, but I am not sure should I put "in" or "on". Or is it fine to put either one of them?

> 1. James spends his family fortune **on** his opulent lifestyle.
> 2. James spends his family fortune **in** his opulent lifestyle.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those sentences quite works. Presumably you want the past tense, so you need *spent* rather than *spend*. Try something like this:

1. James spent his family fortune on an opulent lifestyle.
2. James spent his family fortune in opulent living.

Perhaps a better word than *spent* is *squandered*. It really gives that sense of *wasted*.

Comment: Hi!Thank you for the rely.May I know why is it wrong to use Spend?

Comment: As in I want to show that he is doing it right now and he will continue this kind of lifestyle. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I use Spends instead, is it okay?

Comment: You could use spends, but *is spending* would be better, as it is something he is doing over time.

Comment: @YOYO You can look up the word spend in the dictionary and consider the meaning of the examples where they use spend in simple present tense.

Comment: @ralph.m Deeply appreciate your help!